# Play swf file once on mouseover using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, flash

i need to play a .swf flash file when i mouse over one of my links so

```
<a href="123.html" onMouseOver=" PLAY MY SWF ONCE  ">123</a>
```

can you please help me achieve this using javascript

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to use ExternalInterface to call an Actionscript function from your HTML page.
Have a look at the docs, they have better examples that what I could come up with in a few lines

http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/

But the general setup would be an Actionscript function to play the movie once and this function would be called from javascript via ExternalInterface.

Answer (score 1):

Add the following code to the html just below the swf movie:

```
<a href="javascript:document.movie.Play()">&#9658;play </a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
<a href="javascript:document.movie.StopPlay()">&#9553;pause</a>
```

Notes:
`&#9658;` generates the play icon ►
`&#9553;` generates the pause icon ║
`&nbsp;` forces spaces to occurs
the name of the flash swf movie is "movie" but you can call it anything if you change all occurrences of the name.